# Can I use flutter packages in my app and upload in playstore?

Tags: flutter, dart

Are there any issues if I upload in the play store? Mean any legal issues or copyright infringements?

Comment: If you are referring to packages from pub.dev, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Can i use any package from pub.dev without any issues in future?

Comment: Yes yes. That's what pub.dev is meant for!

Comment: Do i need to display license content in my app and credit to publisher?

Comment: Regarding that, you will need to look into type of license the package has.

Comment: Yes you can as long as you’re using a specific version of package and developer doesn’t introduce any breaking change. You will have to take into account the breaking changes only when you’re upgrading to newer version of the package to take advantage of new features. Check rating of the packages before you add them as dependency. Usually stable packages don’t introduce code breaking changes.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether i can use flutter.dev packages without any credit or not?

Comment: About the licensing, you don’t need to display any license content in your code or app. All packages added to pub.dev have some kind of open-source license.

Comment: @Rahul pub is the package manager for flutter. So you will get packages for flutter from pub.dev, all packages have an open source license so you should not need any credit for using them.

Comment: @AkashSarode That's not true. An open-source license does not mean you can get away without providing credit.

Comment: So,How do i use these for commercial purposes,mean the process?